# MongoDB Distinct and Find using Express

Tags: mongodb, express

I am trying to build an API, however I have come across a roadblock.
There are many non-unique "Makes" in my "styles" collection, and I would like get all "Makes" with category from user input (eg: Sedan) and display only unique "Make" objects that pass the category comparison.

NOTE: I am not using 'Mongoose', I'm using the native driver.

How can I chain `distinct` and `find` methods(using express)?

With the following code:

```
  router.get('/makes/:category', function(req, res) {
  var collection = db.get().collection('styles')

  console.log(req.params.category)

  collection.distinct('make').find({'categories.vehicleStyle': req.params.category}, {'make': 1}).toArray(function(err, docs) {
    res.send(docs)
  })
})
```

Expected Output:

```
[
    {
    "Make": "Acura",
    "Make: "BMW"
    }
]
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: collection.distinct(...).find is not a function
    at C:\path\server\routes\api.js:67:31
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\path\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\path\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\path\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\path\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at C:\path\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
    at param (C:\path\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:354:14)
    at param (C:\path\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:365:14)
    at Function.process_params (C:\path\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:410:3)
    at next (C:\path\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
```

Comment: You can try `collection.distinct('make',{'categories.vehicleStyle': req.params.category}).toArray(function(err, docs) {
    res.send(docs)
  })`

Comment: This works! thanks so much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

Aggregation Operations MongoDB also provides db.collection.distinct()

[Documentation on distinct:](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/#Aggregation-Distinct)

[distinct](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html#distinct)

[distinct command against a collection](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Collection.html#distinct)